# How to disable a button with in a subform from mainform

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I wan to Disable a command button from main form to subform

I have tried:

```
Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform2].Form!Command26.Enabled = False
```

I expect to disable the command 26 button which is in subform

[the navigationsubform2 i refer to is customer form and the button is the add record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMxoF.png)

Comment: Do you really need the whole "map"? Is this not inside a function in the Form were you can use `Me.`?

Comment: i also tried Me.NavigationSubform2.Command26.Enabled = False

Comment: `Forms![Navigation Form].[NavigationSubform2].Form!Command26.Enabled = False` try that, i think the second `!` should be a dot.

Comment: RunTime Error 2456

Comment: Microsoft access cannot find the field Command 26 reference in your expression

Comment: `Me!NavigationSubform2.Form!Command26.Enabled = False`

Comment: @Folks getting confused with the `!` bang operator: stop it. The bang operator is shorthand notation for an implicit call to an object's *default member*, passing whatever follows *as a string literal* and making every single subsequent member call *late-bound*, i.e. you don't get intelisense, no compile-time validation, no parameter tooltips, nothing. Instead of `Form!ControlName.Enabled`, do `Form.Controls("ControlName").Enabled`. The bang operator needs to be thrown into Mt.Doom.

Comment: This time it cannot find the field navigationSubform2 in my expreession

Comment: @Mathieu so back to `Me.Controls("Command26").Enable = False` ?

Comment: @RicardoA doesn't that make the code much clearer, explicit, and unambigious? What do you mean, "back to"? Back to early-bound code that the compiler can validate and call out a typo in? Yes, absolutely.

Comment: If you need to references other forms, use explicit form variables instead of generic collections of generic forms.

Comment: @Mathieu I meant "back to my original reply of [Why are you not using `Me`...]" I was agreeing with you.

Comment: @RicardoA lol sorry I completely misread that! Yeah, definitely. =)